# Simple AWK command to check if the directory path is correctly written

Tags: awk

The POSIX portable file name character set consists of the upper case letters A to Z, the lower case letters a to z, the decimal digits 0 to 9, the full stop, the underscore, and the hyphen. I want to produce an error if the field is not so.
I already can check that the field must start with a "/" but am having difficulty reporting errors for illegal characters within the file path given.
The code I have:

```
{if ($6 !~ /[a-zA-Z0-9_\/.-]{0,100}$/) print NR ": ERROR The directory contains illegal characters" }
```

This doesn't find illegal characters and report them as it should. 
Input: /Bin**/home
Output: Warning illegal characters found (Because of the "**")

Looking to fix my AWK command.

Comment: What implementation of `awk` is it? IIRC they don't all support the `{m,n}` repetition specifier.

Comment: I did awk --version and got awk version 20070501

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: OS El Capitan on this machine

Comment: For some strange reason, you're checking whether the last 100 characters of the path are in that set, not the entire path.  If the path is, say, the character `$` followed by 100 `a`-s, it passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about this ?

```
awk '$6~/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\/.-]/{print NR ":Illegal Characters"}' filename
```